# rake aborted! cannot load such file -- indirizzo

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

I tried running `rake db:reset` in my rails application after bundle install. The following message is displayed

```
rake aborted!
cannot load such file -- indirizzo
/home/xyz/Desktop/Signup4/app/models/concerns/address_validation.rb:2:in `<module:AddressValidation>'
/home/xyz/Desktop/Signup4/app/models/concerns/address_validation.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/home/xyz/Desktop/Signup4/app/models/location.rb:2:in `<class:Location>'
/home/xyz/Desktop/Signup4/app/models/location.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/home/xyz/Desktop/Signup4/db/seeds.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => db:setup => db:seed
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

`bundle show Indirizzo` displays

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/Indirizzo-0.1.7
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me the problem is in correct `require`.
According to readme https://github.com/daveworth/Indirizzo#usage it should be

```
require 'Indirizzo'
```

but the fact that it does not work (the same error).

It think it should be the same as in the internal lib https://github.com/daveworth/Indirizzo/blob/master/lib/indirizzo.rb

```
require 'indirizzo/address'
```

after this I manage to complete this example `Indirizzo::Address.new("some address")`

Comment: Hmm, I got the same error.
I looked at the source and notice that gem itself `require 'indirizzo/address'` https://github.com/daveworth/Indirizzo/blob/master/lib/indirizzo.rb
And after this I manage to complete the example from usage `Indirizzo::Address.new("some address")`

Comment: This worked for me (the latter solution)! Thanks for your help.