# NameError (uninitialized constant HomesController::Indirizzo): Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, rubygems, nameerror, uninitialized-constant

I've deployed my app to Heroku and am getting the the following error:

```
v2014-08-29T01:59:06.582118+00:00 app[web.1]: NameError (uninitialized constant    HomesController::Indirizzo):
```

I am using the Indirizzo gem and it's showing as being install on Heroku, but I am still getting that error. I have tried

```
gem 'Indirizzo', require 'Indirizzo'
```

in my gem file as one post suggested but that didnt work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a file (config/initializers/require_indirizzo.rb) to require it, like so:

```
require 'Indirizzo'
```

If this does not work, you may try the [solution posted by gotva](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18714481/525478) and use this instead:

```
require 'indirizzo/address'
```

Comment: The firsts still didnt work - but the second option did. I guess heroku doesn't like capitalized letters.